# How to refresh grid view height to the size of its dynamic content?

Tags: android

I'm using and adapter to render a the following grid view:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridViewOpciones"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="2" >
</GridView>
```

Said adapter is set to the grid view in the following lines of code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    final GridView gridViewOpciones = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridViewOpciones);
    OpcionesAdapter adapter = new OpcionesAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), R.id.gridViewOpciones, getTransactions());
    gridViewOpciones.setAdapter(adapter);
    ...
}
```

This is my adapter code:

```
public class OpcionesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Transaccion> {

    private List<Transaccion> transacciones;
    private Context context;

    public OpcionesAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<Transaccion> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.transacciones = objects;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return transacciones != null ? transacciones.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Transaccion getItem(int position) {
        return transacciones != null ? transacciones.get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Button boton = new Button(context);
        Transaccion transaccion = getItem(position);
        boton.setText(transaccion.getNombre());
        boton.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(
                transaccion.getImagen(), null, null, null);
        ...
        return boton;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm setting programatically an image to the transaccion buttons inside the gridview. The problem I'm having is that the grid view is not refreshing its height to the dynamic height of its content, with the set images and everything.

Let me be more especific: the arrayList transacciones has exactly 4 objects right now. The problem is, if I leave the layout height of the grid as wrap_content it only shows part of the first 2 buttons. But if I leave it as, say, 300dp, all 4 are shown correctly. Unfortunately, that's not the way to go as I want the height of the grid to be dynamic and wrap its content.

Researching I saw a lot of post using the following lines of code for this:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
gridViewOpciones.invalidateViews();
```

I tried but doesn't seem to have any effect. Perhaps I'm not placing them where I should. Could you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You would call notifyDataSetChanged() whenever you add or remove something from the gridView.   The dynamic height won't change based on notifyDataSetChanged() though.  It simply will update the views data after you've added/removed something from the grid.

You can change LayoutParams after you've added/removed something from the grid ifyou want to change the actual size of the grid however..

Comment: You're right, I don't add or remove anything to the grid after setting the adapter. Where should I place the line of code you mentioned?

Comment: You could try putting the code in getView.. but you want to resize the  view every time you change the image? why don't you set the boton to have layoutParams wrap_content?

Comment: Actually, the buttons are being displayed correctly. Let me be more especific: the arrayList transacciones has exactly 4 objects right now. The problem is, if I leave the layout height of the grid as wrap_content it only shows part of the first 2 buttons. But if I leave it as, say, 300dp, all 4 are shown correctly. But that's not the desired behavior as I want the height to be dynamic.

Comment: try setting the height as 0dp and make the layout_weight = 1